# how can I get gcp stackdriver logs via python script?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, encoding, utf-8, google-cloud-stackdriver

I want to get stackdriver logs via python script without sinks.

I have a read permission in my stackdriver logging project. So I can read logs using "gcloud logging read" command.
But when I try to write a log to the file, Unicode characters is displayed as ??.
(When writing to stdout instead of writing to a file, it looks fine.)

I want to read the log in a different way than the gcloud SDK.
So I want to download the log of GCP using python. Unfortunately I don't have sinks permission so I have to use read. Is there an API document I can refer to?

Thanks :)

Comment: Ask for having the sink permission. Rewriting an existing service is time consuming and useless.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the [appcfg tool is used to download logs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/downloading-logs#requesting_the_logs). This tool is now deprecated. Currently the replacement, Cloud SDK, does not support this download capability; however, you can view your logs using the [gcloud app log commands](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/logs).

Don't forget the permissions.
“[The sink's writer identity does not have permission to write logs to the destination. Errors occur until the sink's writer has permission to write log entries to the destination.](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2#user_interface)”

Please check this [Using exported logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/using_exported_logs) for more details and this [link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview#download-log-entries) to [Download log entries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview#download-log-entries).